# Mixing text and images causes incorrect vertical positioning

Tags: itext

Using iTextSharp version 5.5.8 (same bug existed in 5.5.7), there's an unpleasant bug when you add images to Chapters and Sections - the images and the section headings start out OK but quickly become offset relative to each other.

The PDF generated from the following code starts out correctly, it says "Section 1" and below it is the image.  The next section ("Section 2") has a little of the image overlapping the section text, the next section is even worse, etc.  I think it's the text that's mal-positioned, not the image.

Is this a known iTextSharp bug?

```
    static Document m_doc = null;
    static BaseFont m_helvetica = null;
    static Font m_font = null;
    static PdfWriter m_writer = null;

    static Image m_image = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        m_doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

        m_helvetica = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        m_font = new Font(m_helvetica, 10.0f);

        m_writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(m_doc, new FileStream("Output.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        m_writer.StrictImageSequence = true;

        m_doc.Open();

        m_doc.Add(new Chunk("Created by iTextSharp version " + new iTextSharp.text.Version().GetVersion, m_font));

        Chapter chapter = new Chapter("Chapter 1", 1);
        chapter.TriggerNewPage = false;

        if (m_image == null)
        {
            m_image = Image.GetInstance(new Uri("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2002307628/Captura_de_pantalla_2012-03-17_a_la_s__22.14.48.png"));
            m_image.ScaleAbsolute(100, 100);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Section section = chapter.AddSection(18, "Section " + (i + 1));
            section.Add(new Chunk("   ", m_font));
            section.Add(m_image);
        }

        m_doc.Add(chapter);

        m_doc.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation for the Java version](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Section.html):

> A `Section` is a part of a `Document` containing other `Section`s, `Paragraph`s, `List` and/or `Table`s.

Further looking at the [`Add()`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Section.cs#l277) method in the C# source we see:

> Adds a Paragraph, List, Table or another Section

Basically, instead of a `Chunk` use a `Paragraph`. So instead of this

```
section.Add(new Chunk("   ", m_font));
```

Use this:

```
section.Add(new Paragraph(new Chunk("   ", m_font)));
```

Or even just this:

```
section.Add(new Paragraph("   ", m_font));
```

Comment: Since I'm adding an Image to the Section without problem (despite the documentation not saying I can), I don't think I put much stock in the fact that the documentation doesn't say you can add a Chunk to a Section.  I'm thinking your solution is more of a workaround than a fix, but in either case it solves my problem - thanks!