# I don't want to rotate page but iTextSharp programmatically rotates my pages

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have `pdf` files in the `"C:\\pdfs\\"` directory. I want to get these pdf files and insert metadatas from the `meta_data.txt` file. With my lock of iTextSharp knowledge, I coded like this:

```
var pdf_files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\pdfs\\", "*.pdf");
var i = 0;
foreach (var pdf_file in pdf_files)
{

    var read = new PdfReader(pdf_file);
    var size = read.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    var document = new Document(size);
    var write = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("C:\\temp\\" + "file_" + i, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));

    var datas = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\pdfs\\" + @"meta_data.txt");
    var str = datas[i].Split('@');


    document.AddTitle(str[1]);
    document.AddSubject(str[2]);
    document.AddCreator(str[3]);
    document.AddAuthor(str[4]);
    document.AddKeywords(str[5]);
    document.Open();

    var cb = write.DirectContent;
    for (var pageNum = 1; pageNum <= read.NumberOfPages; pageNum++)
    {
        document.NewPage();
        var page = write.GetImportedPage(read, pageNum);
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
    document.Close();
    read.Close();
    File.Delete(pdf_file);
    File.Move("C:\\temp\\" + "file_" + i, "C:\\created\\" + "file_" + i);

    i++;
}
```

This codes get an instance of main pdf files, while creation to `temp` directory, injects metadatas and later move the `created` directory. I don't find more practical method than this.
Anyway, in some pdf files (generated as an original pdf file) there is no problem like this:
[image]
But some other pdf files (generated from scan or very old dated pdf file) are rotated programmatically. And it seems disgusting like this:
[image]
Worse than all, I don't know how I fix the problem. Could you help me how I manage this problem.

Comment: The reason is that you chose a non-optimal way to merge documents with itext which does not copy all properties of the original page (because the methods involved were designed for a different use case). Use a merging solution based on `PdfCopy` instead of `PdfWriter`, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15945467/1729265).

Comment: Please read the official documentation: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/adding-metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to this question looks like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
    new FileStream("C:\\temp\\" + "file_" + i, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))) {
    Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;
    info["Title"] = "Hello World stamped";
    info["Subject"] = "Hello World with changed metadata";
    info["Keywords"] = "iText in Action, PdfStamper";
    info["Creator"] = "Silly standalone example";
    info["Author"] = "Bruno Lowagie";
    stamper.MoreInfo = info;
}
```

[Habip OĞUZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1372430/habip-o%C4%9Euz) ignored what I wrote in [Chapter 6](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) of "iText in Action - Second Edition", namely that using `Document`, `PdfWriter` and `AddTemplate()` is wrong when you want to manipulate a single existing PDF. By using `AddTemplate()`, you throw away plenty of features, such as interactivity, structure, and so on. You also create a PDF that is suboptimal because every page will be stored as a Form XObject.

Comment: Oops, indeed. I just saw that the op iterated over a number of input files and thought he wanted to merge and so pointed towards `PdfCopy`. Actually he separately manipulates each pdf, so a `PdfStamper` should be used...

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie - Thank you so much for your reply. In order to don't mislead other developers, I am wiping out my reply that served bad solution (or a non-solution).