# c# LocalReport concatenation. How to merge 2 or more LocalReports rdlc?

Tags: c#, pdf, rdlc

I try to merge LocalRaports(rdlc) in one and then to PDF,

What I tried to use this part from  [here][1] and merge byte arrays:

```
private byte[] Combine(params byte[][] arrays)
{
    byte[] rv = new byte[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
    int offset = 0;
    foreach (byte[] array in arrays) {
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, rv, offset, array.Length);
        offset += array.Length;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This code is good working, it merge byte arrays, but as result in pdf only last report pages. Is it way incorrect?

Comment: Using [THIS solution with iTextSharp in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925616/how-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files-generated-in-run-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)