# Issue with iTextSharp pdf rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have a pdf having signature enabled, when i tried to render it using iTextSharp the signature got disappear. I have researched this issue on many platforms but not able to find any solution.

here is my code

```
private void BuildPDF(ref Document doc, ref PdfWriter writer)
    {
        int numberOfPages = 0;
        int currentPageNumber = 0;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int rotation;
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService(ReportServiceUrl, ReportServiceTimeout);
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(ReportName);
            currentPageNumber = 0;
            numberOfPages = reader2.NumberOfPages;
            while (currentPageNumber < numberOfPages)
            {
                currentPageNumber += 1;
                doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
                doc.NewPage();
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader2, currentPageNumber);
                rotation = reader2.GetPageRotation(currentPageNumber);
                if ((rotation == 90) || (rotation == 270))
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader2.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageNumber).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }
```

Please help me out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call *"rendering"* appears to be "adding the content of each page to a new page of some target document".

If by *"a pdf having signature enabled"* you furthermore mean a pdf with an integrated digital signature with visualization, it is obvious that the signature will disappear in your "rendering": *the signature visualization is **not** part of the page content*, it is a widget annotation not copied by your "rendering"!

But even if it was copied, the situation wouldn't be better either: the signature would be located in a document it definitely didn't sign, so the signature would be invalid there,  and I doubt you want a document with invalid signatures.

If you are only interested in the visualization, you should try and flatten the signed pdf before adding the contents to your target document.

---

That been said, if the overall task in your case is collecting the contents of multiple reports in a single pdf, your code doesn't use the appropriate iText classes anyways: for such a task one would use a `PdfCopy` instead of a generic `PdfWriter`, cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945467/1729265).

Comment: I was only interested in visualization, but i was not able to find a correct path, your suggested solution worked perfectly. Thank you, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PdfCopy` to copy the objects other than content.

Note that if you happen to keep the signature appearance it will show up as invalid.

Comment: can you share the code snippet? all i am seeing is pdfCopy is a class and if i am doing writer = new PdfCopy(doc,memstream), nothing is getting loaded in pdf.

Comment: @Mussadiq you'll find a `PdfCopy` example following the link at the end of my answer.