# Why my code is rotating the documents 180 degrees?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have written a C# code that merges two pdf files upon downloading together but it rotates some (not all) documents 180 degrees. I have attached the sample file that I am uploading.

Kindly, help me on this.

[Sample file](https://filebin.net/ur6fywzjj4o7r1gq)

```
try
    {
        string NewFileName = "InspectionReport" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy HHmmss").Replace(" ", "");
        destinationFile = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"/Downloads/CNGCertificates/" + NewFileName + ".pdf");

        int f = 0;

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[f]);

        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;

        Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create));

        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int rotation;

        while (f < sourceFiles.Length)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n)
            {
                i++;
                document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
                document.NewPage();
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }

            }
            f++;
            if (f < sourceFiles.Length)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(sourceFiles[f]);

                n = reader.NumberOfPages;

            }
        }

        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Without looking into much detail: You are handling `rotation == 90` and rotation == 270` so maybe this is just a matter of also checking for `rotation == 180`. Did you try stepping through using the debugger to inspect cases where the unwanted rotation occurs? I would expect this being reproducable.

Comment: Are you sure the source files are correct? And rotation does not say anything about the actual document. If I put a paper upside down in the scanner the rotation will still be 0.

Comment: @Filburt: i have found that the file being uploaded has 270 degrees orientation.

Answer (score 3):

You are handling `rotation` of `90` and `270` identically. Thus, if source pages with a `rotation` value of `90` are handled as you expect, source pages with a `rotation` value of `270` consequentially will end  up upside down.

Thus, you have to handle `270` separately, using the affine transformation rotating the other way:

```
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 1f, -1f, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Width, 0);
```

Similarly you'll have to handle the `180` value separately, too, unless you want such pages to end up upside down:

```
cb.AddTemplate(page, -1f, 0, 0, -1f, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Width, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
```

---

That all being said, you actually shouldn't use a normal `PdfWriter` for merging at all, you should use `PdfCopy`. Using `PdfCopy` you don't have to deal with details like rotation anymore. Furthermore, annotations are copied along and not dropped as with `PdfWriter`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945467/1729265) for example. (If you use a 5.5.x version, you don't have to differentiate between the `PdfCopy` variants mentioned there anymore, you can use the plain `PdfCopy` for all use cases. If you use a 4.x version, though, you do have to pick appropriately.)

Comment: Not *the same*. Similarly to the 270° case, the 180° case needs *its own parameters*. I've edited my answer accordingly.