# Copy PDF with Annotations using iText but Annotations content removed

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

```
for (Integer page : pages) {
                String outFile = out + "_" + page;
                try {
                    int rotation = getRotation(reader, page);
                    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    document = createDocument(reader, page, hasHeader);
                    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
                    document.open();
                PdfImportedPage p = writer.getImportedPage(reader, page);
                Image image = Image.getInstance(p);
                addImageToPdf(rotation, document, image);

                    file.add(FileUtilities.getFile(outFile));           
                    
                }
```

This code is working fine but output pdf does not have the annotation content it automatically get removed so is there any solution to fix it we are using itext 2.1.7 version

Comment: Consider using `PdfCopy` instead of `PdfWriter`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945467/1729265).

Comment: can you please share the code snippet what change I need to do

Comment: Can you first describe what you exactly want to do? If you just want to copy a PDF then do a file copy - but this can't be all - could it? So you want to concatenate two PDFs which can contain form fields?